# OnClick Close DateTime Picker

Tags: javascript, opencart

I have implemented a close button on my datetime picker by making changes in my bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js. Here is the code.

```
<tr><td><button class="label label-danger" onclick="this.blur()">Close</button></td><tr>
```

When I click close, I want this datetime picker window to be closed. I've tried several thing but none are working. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem. But something like this can work.

```
<button class="label label-danger" onclick="javascript:$(document).find(" .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget").hide();">Close</button>
```

Comment: Can this work in js file? The html that i am using is a generated html by bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js and im implementing this code over there.

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked will just a slight modification :)